# Ejecutar consultas MySQL a dos tablas al mismo tiempo y mostrar resultados

Tags: php, mysqli

me gustaría mostrar una consulta de dos tablas que no están relacionadas entre sí. practicamente  contienen los mismos campos id,nombre ,apellido,avatar,fecha 
Tabla "contenido" y tabla "copias", la tabla "copias" en realidad son copias de la tabla "contenido" se copia todo el contenidoo de la tabla "contenido" en la tabla "copias" menos la fecha 
por que a la hora que se hace el copiado de la tabla "contenido" la fecha que agrego es la fecha actual no la que ya la tabla "contenido" tiene
mi punto es que yo quiero mostar todo en html de la tabla "contenido" y la tabla "copias" en 2 divs en un div ira la tabla "contenido" y en otro la tabla "copias" 
ahora lo que yo quiero lograr es lo siguiente mostrar todo en orden segun su fecha no importa si estan en divs separados que a la hora de mostrarse se muesteren en orden por su fecha 
no que me muestre primero todos los divs de copias y luego todos los divs de contenido o primero todos los de contenido y luego los de copias, no no no no lo yo quiero es que se muestren 
uno debajo del otro por orden de fecha ,ejemplo un div de contenido y otro de copias o biseversa segun su fecha. me doy a entender? ojala alguien me ayude o por lo menos me de una idea de como puedo lograrlo gracias!!

mi CODIGO es el siguiente, pero se muestran primero todos los divs de "contenido" y luego todos los divs de "copias"
lo que quiero lograr es el ejemplo que les comente

NOTA:si se preguntas por que hay una copia exacta de la tabla "contenido" es pra propositos determinados de la aplicacion que estoy creando

CODIGO para tabla contenido:

```
<?php
include"conexion.php";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM contenido ORDER BY fecha DESC"); 


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


  <div id="contenido">
       <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <p><?php echo$row["nombre"]?></p>

              </td>
              <td>
               <p><?php echo$row["apellido"]?></p>
              </td>
              <td>
               <p><?php echo$row["fecha"]?></p>
              </td>
              <div>
                <img src="avatars/<?php echo$row["avatar"]?>">

              </div>

            </tr>
       </table>

  </div>
```

CODIGO para tabla copias:

```
<?php

include"conexion.php";

   $query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM copias ORDER BY fecha DESC"); 

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


      <div id="copias">
           <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                   <p><?php echo$row["nombre"]?></p>

                  </td>
                  <td>
                   <p><?php echo$row["apellido"]?></p>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                   <p><?php echo$row["fecha"]?></p>
                  </td>
                  <div>
                    <img src="avatars/<?php echo$row["avatar"]?>">

                  </div>

                </tr>
           </table>

      </div>



  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un union

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO_FECHA
    FROM TABLA1
    WHERE ...
    UNION
    SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO_FECHA
    FROM TABLA2
    WHERE ...
)
ORDER BY CAMPO_FECHA DESC
```

Para los UNION es importante saber que ambas consultas deben tener los mismos campos y del mismo tipo.

Comment: vale entonces solo me daria una consulta? osea a la hora de yo sacar el resultado  de esa consulta como la aplico en los dos divs?

Comment: @zeross pero no esta pidiendo que sea todo unido en un unico div, realmente no se entiende que es lo que quieres.

Comment: Buf pues entonces es verdad que no he entendido la pregunta. ¿@andy, podrías intentar aclarar un poco lo que quieres? Porque a mi tampoco me queda del todo claro.

Comment: sencillo mi sitio web los usuarios podran agregar fotos con su nombre y apellido las el contenido que suban sera guardado en la tabla "contenido" luego podran hacer una copia de esa publicacion ya sea dandole a un boton o algo al momento del usuario hacer una copia de esa publicacion la informacion de esa publicacion se guardara en la tabla "copias" exactamente con la misma informacion de la tabla contenido  , lo que va a variar es la fecha que a la hora de la copia se introducira la hora actual  en cuando se hiso la copia

Comment: ahora lo que yo quiero como dije en el comentario es mostrar el contenido de esas dos tablas mas o menos como la publicaciones de fb o instagram un escroll verdad pero que me aparescan por orden de fecha no importa si estan en dos divs por separado , que a la hora de mostrarse se muestren en orden

Comment: Pues o sigo sin entenderlo o creo que ya tienes la respuesta. En el caso de que quieras mostrarlo en dos tablas por separado puedes hacerlo como lo tienes en tu pregunta y si lo que quieres es que te aparezca todo junto en una sola tabla puedes utilizar un UNION como te indico en esta respuesta.